# AS3 XML node traversal

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, migration, nodes, xmlnode

I am migrating from AS2 to AS3 and ran into trouble grabbing nodes from XML. I am able to grab (and trace) the entire XML file in AS3 but want to be able to store the first tag as a node using firstChild and loop through the tags using nextSibling. But in AS3 the firstChild keeps coming up empty, when my previous AS2 code would actually grab the content. What am I doing wrong? (and I can't call tags by their names because I reuse the code block for multiple xml files)

```
var eRoot = exampleXML.firstChild;
while (eRoot != null) {
  //do stuff
  eRoot= eRoot.nextSibling;
}
```

My test XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<content>
    <version>cd</version>
    <lessonlock>~-*~-*</lessonlock>
    <expiryDate>**#*#**##**##**##*##********###*</expiryDate>
    <isSpanish>true</isSpanish>
    <server>http://www.exampleSite.com</server>
</content>
```

Comment: Try using XMLDocument for as2-style xml http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/xml/XMLDocument.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because neither `firstChild` nor `nextSibling` exist as properties on an AS3 XML object.  The way you are doing it, you are searching for the nodes `<firstChild>` and `<nextSibling>`.

You should read the [API for XML](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/XML.html), and better yet, [Adobe's guide to E4X](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e72.html).

Comment: right, I didn't understand that. but the problem still exists because I'm using different XML files with different tags in each- I don't want to have to know the name of the tag beforehand in order to grab it- so it seems that there is no longer a way to do this. unless I maybe use string manipulation to split up the tags and store them into some other datastructure.

Comment: You should *really* read those sources I linked to.  You can of course use XMLLists to traverse through child nodes without knowing their names: `node.*` will return all children, `node..*` all descendants, etc.

Comment: I had read the first source in entirety yesterday. when I tried XMLList yesterday I could only create a list of length 1 with the entire xml file in the first slot. but I probably missed something so I'll keep trying that route, thank you.